# How should I rotate rsyslog documents stored in mysql

Tags: mysql, logrotate, rsyslog

I have setup rsyslog to dump syslog data into mysql so that LogAnalyzer can easily access and interact with it.

How do I automate a job to remove syslog data of a certain age for the mysql database so it doesn't fill my HD?

Answer (score 2):

Have a cronjob executing a query like the following once a day:

```
 delete from syslogtable where timestampfield < subdate(curdate(), 31);
```

Here, `syslogtable` is the table in question, `timestampfield` is the the DATE/TIME field containing the date of the log entry and deleted will a log entries older than 31 days. Adapt to your local situation (database, table and field names and the desired time to keep log entries).

Answer (score -1):

Proper syntax for what @Sven said:

```
mysql -u database-userid -pdatabase-password -e “DELETE FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)” database-name
```

This one will delete data older than one day.
Use with crontab to your liking.